# Google Translate Not Working on Edge and IOS

Tags: javascript, google-translation-api

I have added the Google Translator code to one of the test websites. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox. However, if a user is using IE or Safari, the google translator does not appear.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({  
      pageLanguage: 'en', 
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
    }, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#google_translate_element').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
      $('.goog-te-menu-value span:first').html('Translate');
      $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item-selected .text').html('Translate');    
        }, 100);
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

My question is: Is there a translation app like google translator that I can implement to the website for free (ideal)/is not expensive to use? Or is there a way to modify what I have above that will work for all browsers?

**Update:** Is there a way I can use the google translate but create my own button so it is visible in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I was once inside this predicament, what you need do is remove any google translator script you have on your **HEADER TAG** to Your **FOOTER** or **BODY TAG** Because some browser does support that header script rendering.

STOP INSERTING GOOGLE TRANSLATOR ON YOUR HEADER TAG..